# Adding a Folder path in Matlab to access a different folder with Matlab data on Mac

Tags: matlab

I am trying to load a folder path on mac to a folder of MATLAB data sets.

This is the code I am using:

```
folder_path = '/Documents/2020/Root Locus/Data';

files = dir(fullfile(folder_path,'*.mat'))
```

The file I am running the code from is located in the root locus folder. My files variable keeps appearing empty as nothing has loaded to it, any help?

Comment: the command is correct but probably your path not. Are you sure that you folder is reachable from your *Current Folder* like this (note that it the script/function where you use this command does not necessarily need to be in your *Current Folder* but may just lie on your *path*, which may mix up your relative path, from which your want to load

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the path as either the relative path from Matlab's current folder or the absolute path for the system. An absolute path will start with `/` and specify the location from the topmost system directory. Relative paths do not start with `/`.

If you are running Matlab from `Root Locus`, then try `folder_path = 'Data';`

The absolute path makes the code more portable, so also try `folder_path = '/Users/<username>/Documents/2020/Root Locus/Data';`